# Bitwise operators comparison error

Tags: c, macros, arm, bit, iar

compiler: IAR
platform: stm32f4

i have this code but it dont work as expected. 
some one can explain me why?

```
#define byteGetbit(x,y) ((x) & (0x01 << (y)))

volatile t_uint8 test=0xFF;
if(byteGetbit(test,0x03)==1){ //always false
   printf("hello"); //can't reach the code here
   test = 0;
}
```

workaround:

```
if(byteGetbit(test,0x03)){
   printf("hello");
   test = 0;
 }
```

Comment: `printf("%d\n", byteGetbit(test, 0x03));`

Comment: @user1111998 Your logic `if(byteGetbit(test,0x03)==1)` and `#define byteGetbit(x,y) ((x) & (0x01 << (y)))` always yields result which is not equal to 1. This is mainly because of left shifting three times obviously results in multiplication and thus your results should be always greater than 1 for all non-zero positive values of x.

Answer (score 2):

`byteGetbit` yields a value with the corresponding bit set or clear, so to test for the bit set you have to either check:

```
if(byteGetbit(test,0x03) == 0x03)
```

or

```
if(byteGetbit(test,0x03))  // test if byteGetbit(test,0x03) != 0
```

Answer (score 1):

`((x) & (0x01 << (y)))` is not a logical operation, thus, it does not yield a 0 or 1 result. In this particular example, `((x) & (0x01 << (y)))` results in 0 (for the case that bit `y` is disabled in `x`, or it results in a binary number with only bit `y` set, which *can* be 1 (if `y == 0`), but it doesn't *have* to be 1 (and it never is for the case that `y` > 0).

If you want `byteGetbit` to evaluate to either 1 or 0, like logical operations, you should use this instead:

```
#define byteGetbit(x,y) (((x) & (0x01 << (y))) ? 1 : 0)
```

This will evaluate to 1 if bit `y` is set on `x` and to 0 otherwise. In other words, it gives you the value of the `y`-th bit on `x`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't read the bit, but you isolate the bit at it's current locations.

You should change byteGetbit to this:

```
#define byteGetbit(x,y) ((x >> y) & 0x01)
```

This will shift the bit to bit 0 and then isolate it.